# Reload database before some test in phpunit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm currently developing unit tests with phpunit, and symfony 5.
On a previous job using behat, we were able to reload the database only for the tests having a specific tag. I'd like to do something similar. I know there is the setUp() method and the @before annotation, but they don't let me do thing for some tests and not others...

Ideally, I'd like to have a @reloadBase annotation to put on the test methods that are targetted by this, which would be bound to a reloadBase() method or something like; or at least something similar, but so far I couldn't come up with a way to do it.

I guess there is the possibility to put those tests in a separate file which would have a setUp method doing so, but that's not so great, I'd like to keep my current file organization...

Any ideas ? Thank you

Comment: [DAMADoctrineTestBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html) can isolate **each test** with specific data (using [Fixtures](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)), integrated into Doctrine and easy to use.

Comment: Interesting bundle, but it doesn't seem to allow to reload the fixtures only for some specific tests, does it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This bundle is made for unit testing. So database changes during an Unit Test should NOT be influence other unit test.

Comment: Sure but a unit test doesn't always change the database, therefore there is not need to reload the base each time

Comment: The DAMA bundle doesn't reload the database if you didn't change this database.

Comment: indeed, only a rollback, which is fine I guess. It would be great to be able to activate it only for unit testing though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ideas:

**Trait/Base Class**
Create a trait or a common base class with a method that does all the reloading stuff. Use the trait or extend the base class and call it just in the methods that need the reload.

**Extension**
Implement an [extension](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/extending-phpunit.html#extending-the-testrunner). The `BeforeTestHook` will be called for each test with a string consisting of the class and method name. You can either use an annotation reader (e.g. [Doctrine's](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations)) or use [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) and parse the doc block yourself to check whether the `@reloadBase` annotation exists on that method.

Comment: Yes ! The extension way is doing what I want ! Thanks a lot !